# Zooming in Firefox Causes Page Layout to Break

Tags: html, firefox, layout, css

I'm having trouble with this page: http://seatgeek.com/atlanta-hawks-tickets/.  If you zoom out one level from the "normal" setting in Firefox, the page looks like this: [image: Example broken image].  This happens with both versions 3.6 and 4.0 of FF.  It does not happen with Webkit.

Clearly the problem lies in the elements within the "list_details" div.  The problem can be fixed by decreasing the width of the "col1" or "col2" spans by 1px or by increasing the "vevent" li element by 1px, but these fixes cause the design to render improperly.

If you add up the width of "col1" and "col2", also taking into account their horizontal padding and border, the total width is 647px.  But it only displays properly in Firefox (when zoomed out one level) when the "vevent" element, which contains the two, has a width of 648px.  Why is that?

Comment: One thing I should have added: I've tried validating the markup, and while it doesn't fully pass, most of the errors are JS warnings that don't seem relevant here.

Comment: I've just taken a look at it on FF 3.6.17 and the layout remains perfect when I zoom up or down. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Ditto. I looked at it in 3.6 and 4 and did not notice a problem when zooming.

Comment: it certainly looks ok on my FF 3.6.17 and 4 as well (windows)..what Firefox was this? Mac, windows, linux?

Comment: I've just zoomed in with FF 10 and it works!

Answer (score 2):

as this appears to have been bumped,  but the original code is not available, I can say that the difference would have been caused by rounding (or sub pixels), the OP said the problem didn't happen when the div was `648px` wide.. an even number can be halved, or split between 2 columns (OP also mentions 2 columns) quite easily no matter the zoom level

However the odd number`647px`  will have been treated differently by Firefox

I cannot say exactly how as I can no longer see the widths of the two columns, but this blog post by John Resig, may explain better

[**Sub-Pixel Problems in CSS**](http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/)

one possible solution, or at least a helper, is to make sure the available width of the container is always divisible by the number of columns?

Answer (score 1):

removing the `margin-right` from the following css fixed the zoom out issue

```
#left_container .search_details .list_details {
    margin-right: 1px;
}
```

Comment: That does indeed stop it from breaking completely, but it aloso subtly changes the way the right edge of the list looks.  Instead of having a well defined edge (http://cl.ly/5hel) it has a slightly fuzzy one (http://cl.ly/5hBg).  I realize this is a very minor different, but I prefer the non-fuzzy version.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `margin-right:-1px` to the following css. This can fix the zoom out issue.

```
.team-show .static-sidebar {
    line-height: 22px;
    margin-right: -1px;
    position: relative;
    width: 255px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For future reference those looking for a general answer to why zooming can cause layout breaks

http://dev.jeffersonscher.com/resolution.html

Also use relative units to size things

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units